# there is a monic polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $d$, such that all of its coefficients are either $+1$ or $-1$ and $\left|P(t)-2019\right| <1.$

Tags: polynomials

Let $1<t<2$ be a real number. Prove that for all sufficiently large positive integers $d$, there is a monic polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $d$, such that all of its coefficients are either $+1$ or $-1$ and
    $$\left|P(t)-2019\right| <1.$$

This problem is from https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1862283p12600279

I think the dgrozev methods have somewrong,becuase he only prove $|P(t)-2019|\le 1$ ,can you agree with me

Comment: The number $2019$ appears. Therefore you are to give the source lest you are trying to cheat in a running contest.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen,I have edit it.It is 2019 Iran Tst

Comment: Thank you. Retracting my close vote.

Comment: @geromty is my answer below helpful?

Answer (score 2):

I mean, dgrozev specifically points out that he proves $|P(t)-2019| \le 1$ and that an extension needs to be made to $|P(t)-2019| < 1$. He said he can provide that extension, but didn't. So I don't see how you can call his methods "wrong"; he just didn't provide the complete proof.

In any event, I have a proof that shows that at least $50\%$ of all large $d$ have such a polynomial. Clearly, from dgrozev's proof, there is only an issue if there are some $\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_d \in \{\pm 1\}$ with $\epsilon_dt^d+\dots+\epsilon_1 t+\epsilon_0 = 2018$. Now, I claim that if there are such $\epsilon_0,\dots,\epsilon_d$, then there won't be $\epsilon_0',\dots,\epsilon_{d+1}'$ with $\epsilon_{d+1}'t^{d+1}+\dots+\epsilon_1't+\epsilon_0' = 2018$.

To show this claim, it suffices to show that two polynomials with only $\pm 1$ coefficients that are one degree apart have no common roots. It of course suffices to show that any two such polynomials have gcd $1$ over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, which is equivalent to showing any two such polynomials share no common factor in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, which essentially by Gauss's lemma (or its proof) is equivalent to two such polynomials sharing no common factor in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. So suppose for the sake of contradiction that they did share a common factor in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. This common factor must, of course, be monic or have first coefficient $-1$. Then, reducing everything mod $2$, $x^{d+1}+\dots+x+1$ and $x^d+\dots+x+1$ would share a nontrivial common factor in $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$, but they don't since $x^{d+1}+\dots+x+1-x(x^d+\dots+x+1) = 1$.

Comment: Please could you clarify a point in your interesting proof. The two polynomials you give at the end of para 2 have a common value but not necessarily a common root so how did you then proceed?

Comment: @S.Dolan you're right. surprised I didn't notice that (I was playing around with $\pm 1$ polynomials a lot). however, it's easily fixable. all that my last paragraph used was that the two polynomials reduced to $x^{d+1}+\dots+x+1$ and $x^d+\dots+x+1$, so just apply that paragraph to $\epsilon_dt^d+\dots+\epsilon_1 t+[\epsilon_0-2018]$ and $\epsilon_{d+1}'t^{d+1}+\dots+\epsilon_1't+[\epsilon_0'-2018]$ (lucky for me, $2018$ is even :) ).

Comment: Thanks. I assumed that's what you were intending but I wanted to check that I wasn't missing something. Like you, I've played around with these polynomials and I had  convincedmyself that there is a problem with dgrozev's statement about an extension. (See the 'answer' below.)

Answer (score 1):

The method used by dgrozev **cannot** be used to prove the strict inequality because there is nothing in the method to distinguish 2019 from any other integer and yet and yet it's not the case that the result is true for all integers.

Counterexample.

Let $t$ be the golden ratio and let $d$ be 2 modulo 3. Then |P(t)|is either 0 or at least 2.

(To prove this result about |P(t)| first show that it is true for $d=2$ and then use the inequality  $|2t^3-(1+t+t^2)|\ge 2$ to extend the result.)

Comment: This is the better answer, though I can't figure out the proof of $|P(t)-1| \ge 1$. Very nice +1. One very small nitpick though. You should instead say "and yet it's not the case that the result is true for all integers", to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Agreed - thanks. Are you interested in seeing a properly written out proof?

Comment: Yes, if it's not too much work on your part (I'll read it regardless)

Comment: Can I email it?

Comment: Done - it wasn't as long as I thought it was going to be. I could have typed it up in TeX.

Comment: It has been sent successfully according to my computer but I've added an answer below - hope I didn't make too many typos in TeX.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, we can assume that the coefficient of $t^d$ is +1.

If $d=2$
The possibilities for $P(t)$ are $0=-1-t+t^2$ and values which are at least 2 greater than this.

If $d>2$
The terms in $t^{(d-2)},t^{(d-1)}$ and $t^d$ sum to $0$ or at least  $2t^{(d-2)}$.

If they sum to $0$ then we can proceed inductively. Otherwise we have
$$P(t)\ge2t^{(d-2)}-t^{(d-3)}-t^{(d-4)}-t^{(d-5)}-t^{(d-6)}-…$$
$$=t^{(d-3)}+t^{(d-4)}-t^{(d-5)}-t^{(d-6)}-…$$
$$>2t^{(d-4)}-t^{(d-5)}-t^{(d-6)}-…$$        and again we can proceed inductively.

Comment: it went to my spam. anyways, I think you can prove that $2t^{d-2}-t^{d-3}-\dots > 2$ just directly

Comment: but nice solution